# Get Parameter Names used by PowerShell functions

Tags: powershell

In the past week I have been looking at some Powershell best practices. One of these is to re-use Powershell parameter names so commands feel more intuitive.

Does anyone have a function for retrieving parameter names for all functions?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Get-Command](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113309) cmdlet to retrieve all commands and select the parameter names:

```
get-command | % { if ($_.Parameters) {$_.Parameters.Keys }} | select -Unique | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

jisaak's post will get you a list of commands as requested; the best practices I read recommended re-using the Powershell verbs which you can get by:

```
Get-Verb
```

Modules containing modules that don't use the standard verbs generate a nice error:

```
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module '***' include
unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable.
To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again
with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
```

Comment: Microsoft has a list of [approved verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx).